# Mod Rewrite Can't get it to work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Mod Rewrite rule from my existing system

```
#default Lightweight rewriting
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Now we have just purchased a new domain name allheavy.net and i want to use it as a url shortner
as with the current system i have this band page

http://allheavymetal.net/band/band/id/222/name/Metallica

Now i want it so i can go to 
http://allheavy.net/Metallica

*UPDATE 2*
So this is what i have go so far

```
# Match the host, optionally with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?allheavy\.net$
# Ensure the rule doesn't apply to itself
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index/short
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/short/d/$1 [L]

#Lightweight MVC
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?allheavymetal\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

So from this the first rule works and the second rule works independantly

However if the first rule is called the rewritten url (`/index/short/d/Metallica`) but this is then not used when calling the second rule...

Comment: This is in .htaccess rather than the VirtualHost? In .htaccess directory context, don't include a leading `/`, as in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/short/d/$1`. You are using the chain `[C]` flag - if this new rule comes first, a failure will prevent subsequent rules from running. `[C]` is not often used, and it seems like you might want `[L]` there instead.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Well that stopped it breaking the base code but the new one is not working if i go to http://allheavy.net/Metallica
I should be seeing the response for http://www.allheavymetal.net/index/short/d/Metallica insted i get a 500 Error???

Comment: Probably you're getting a rewrite loop. You need to not match the processor URI. Something like  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/short/d`  along with the `allheavy.net` conditions should do it. If so, I'll write it all up as an answer.

Comment: Wait sorry, that should be negated `!/index/short/d`

Comment: nope still not working :(

Comment: it's not a redirect loop chrome fails with a request loop problem

Comment: Please post you complete current set of rules

Comment: Same thing... If you look at the Apache error log, it will be complaining about a redirect loop. The problem is that `^(.*)` always matches, including `/index/short/d`

Comment: Ah, the thing I suggested was for an additional `RewriteCond`, not a modification/negation to your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: why you have `!` in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ !/index/short/d/$1 [L]`?

Comment: @tttony That's addressed in an earlier comment...

Comment: you have to put the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index/short`, to avoid redirect loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your original two `RewriteCond` into one by making the `www.` optional with `()?`. Then you'll need an additional condition to make sure the subsequent `RewriteRule` does not match the processing script URI `/index/short/d`.

```
# Match the host, optionally with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?allheavy\.net$
# Ensure the rule doesn't apply to itself
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index/short
# This should not match a leading / in directory context
# Use the [L] flag instead of the [C] chain flag to allow
# further rules to match if this does not
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/short/d/$1 [L]
# Or if the same index.php will process this, omit [L]
# allowing the rule to continue execution and match the catch-all
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/short/d/$1

# Then place your original generic catch-all rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

All of this assumes that the script at `allheavy.net/index/short/d` is already able to successfully process and serve the target script via its URL shortener.

#### Some additional research

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?allheavy\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index/short
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/short/d/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The above will first rewrite through `/index/short/d/$1` and then into `index.php`, however, the controller URI `/index/short/d/xxxxx` is received by PHP in `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`. If your controller is able to make use of that, this might work for you.

Comment: Nope this still does not work i get the same thing a 500 error for allheavy.net but the main site MVC system the last rule is working still and allheavy.net is a Alias of the same virtual host as allheavymetal.net

Comment: however this does not work either http://allheavy.net/index/short/d/Metallica it still 500 errors

Comment: You need to look in your Apache error log to see what the 500 error actually is.

Comment: `[Sun Aug 31 05:32:28.855072 2014] [core:error] [pid 23517] [client 2.99.129.186:18211] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun Aug 31 05:32:28.855137 2014] [core:error] [pid 23517] [client 2.99.129.186:18211] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
`

Comment: That's still a rewrite loop. Do you have _exactly_ as I have above? Does the same `index.php` script handle processing of the URL shortener?

Comment: i have exactly what you have above, and yeah it's an MVC index.php hence the `/index/short/d/$1`

Comment: @MartinBarker the idea is to rewrite `allheavy.net/d/Metallica` to `allheavy.net/index/short/d/Metallica` internally in the server

Comment: Note - I just added another condition above to ensure that the catch-all rule does not run when the host is allheavy.net - that is probably the cause of the loop, since that rule would have matched with any domain...

Comment: Does the directory `index/short/d` actually exist?

Comment: it does not exist it's a controller action with a url parameter the newest one breaks the Base MVC rewrite

Comment: So the same index.php handles both types. If you remove the `[L]` from the first group, and remove the `RewriteCond` %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?allheavy\.net` I added from the second group, the first should rewrite internally, then fall through to the second.

Comment: @MartinBarker I've been doing a little more research too and will update above. I can get Apache to process the shortener request correctly and end up with index.php, however the requested shortener path ends up in `REDIRECT_URL`

Comment: cool i dont care how it get's to that action of the MVC as long as the data is there and i can get it... :)

Comment: Well, try what I just posted then - inside your controller, do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` and check if REDIRECT_URL is populated. It is for me...

Comment: I got a 500 Error using your newest version

Comment: @MartinBarker Gah - this is why dealing with mod_rewrite on Stack Overflow is so frustrating. I setup two local test subdomains and made these rewrites work with my own paths. Translated to your paths, they don't work... Hang on and I'll try to work through it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60332/discussion-between-martin-barker-and-michael-berkowski).